# How can i make slider effect like notification bar for my activity in android?

Tags: android

I want to open another layout or screen by how we will open notification by shuttering. i want that from bottom to top and and close it to top to bottom. so can you please help me how to do that ?

Comment: You just want your activity to be animated? or you mean user should be able to drag it down and push it up?

Comment: Have you tried SlidingDrawer? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html